# Haskell record pattern matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, record, algebraic-data-types

I'm looking for a way to simplify function patterns when the actual data is not required:

```
data X = A | B String | C Int Int String
myfn :: X -> Int
myfn A = 50
myfn (B _) = 200
myfn (C _ _ _) = 500
```

Is there a way to make a simpler pattern for matching C, just discarding the values?

hsdev adds a hint "Hint: use record patterns", but Google did not help me there.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can use record patterns like this:

```
data X = A | B {name :: String} | C {x::Int, y::Int, name::String}

myfn :: X -> Int
myfn A = 50
myfn B{} = 200
myfn C{} = 500
```

Record patterns allow you to give names to the fields of the constructors.
you can also do things like:

```
myfn C{name=n} = length n
```

so you can see that you can pattern match only on the specific field you need.

**Note:** you can use the *empty* record pattern even with data types that do not use record syntax:

```
data A = A Int | B Int Int

myfn A{} = 1
myfn B{} = 2
```

This is fine.
There a number of other extensions related to record patterns:

- `RecordWildCards` allows you to write things like `C{..}` which is equivalent to the pattern: `C{x=x, y=y, name=name}`, i.e. it matches all fields and you now have in scope `x` with the value matched for the `x` field etc.
- `NamedFieldPuns` allows you to write `C{name}` to be equivalent to `C{name=name}`, so that `name` is now in scope and contains the value matched for the `name` field.

Keep in mind that using record patterns doesn't prevent you from using your constructors in a positional way, so you can still write:

```
myfn (B _) = 200
```

It only *adds* functionality.

Comment: Great, thanks. I actually tried C{_} and C{..}, to no avail. Just one character too much. ^^

Comment: Shame that Google doesn't help you much with "haskell record pattern". I've renamed the question, maybe that'll make it more discoverable for others.

Comment: @theduke: Note also that you can use the empty record pattern (`B{}`) even if you declared `B` to be a normal, non-record data type.

Comment: @Lii That is something I didn't think about. I'll add a mention to the answer.

Comment: @Lili thanks for pointing it out. To me, it was obvious from the answer anyway, though.